# Can't install GCC48 via Homebrew - curl error (auth?)

Tags: gcc, homebrew

I need c11 support but I can't seem to install gcc48 from homebrew:

```
$ brew install gcc48
==> Downloading ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/snapshots/4.8.0-RC-20130316/gcc-4.8.0-RC-20130316.tar.bz2

curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory
Error: Download failed: ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/snapshots/4.8.0-RC-20130316/gcc-4.8.0-RC-20130316.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `curl` isn't giving the proper error thereby misleading you into thinking that it is some sort of auth issue.

The real issue is that the specified directory doesn't exist on the ftp server.  Maybe this is a homebrew issue.

```
$ wget ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/snapshots/4.8.0-RC-20130316/gcc-4.8.0-RC-20130316.tar.bz2
--2013-07-19 15:16:06--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/snapshots/4.8.0-RC-20130316/gcc-4.8.0-RC-20130316.tar.bz2
           => `gcc-4.8.0-RC-20130316.tar.bz2'
Resolving gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)... 209.132.180.131
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)|209.132.180.131|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/gcc/snapshots/4.8.0-RC-20130316 ... 
No such directory `pub/gcc/snapshots/4.8.0-RC-20130316'.
```

Comment: Thanks - I think it is indeed an issue with the install for gcc